# Calculating curvature in SAGA?

Tags: raster, dem, saga, arcgis-pro, curvature

I have calculated curvature using ArcGIS (curvature) and SAGA (Slope, Aspect, Curvature; based on 9 parameter 2nd order polynom (Zevenbergen & Thorne 1987) method), however, the output rasters are not the same.

I've done some research and now I understand how curvature works in ArcGIS:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-curvature-works.htm

But it's still a mystery to me how SAGA calculates curvature.

Which formula is used?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across similar questions [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37066/how-to-calculate-terrain-curvature) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/e9d07075/) but none have provide responses to what you are looking for.

However, I did find this question [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/354013/thread/b1fe9ebc/) that yielded a [link](http://saga.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0.7plus-pdfsg-2build2/Morphometry_8cpp_source.html) which provides a module library containing the formula and additional details. Plus this academic peer-reviewed [paper](http://www.geos.ed.ac.uk/homes/s0451705/hurst_eteal_2012_jgr.pdf) that delves into SAGA and a use case study.